# Is there a way to determine successes in a python dice roller?

Tags: python, random, dice

I am new to programming (like *very new*) and I decided to make a dice roller for my favorite RPG, Vampire the Masquerade. For those who don't know, when you want to make a roll in VtM, you make dice pools of d10s (ten sided dice) and then whether you succeed or not is based on the amount of "successes" you rolled; any dice result of 6 or more.

So far, i've managed to make a basic roller that just rolls d10s:

```
#"d" is the number of dice
def roll(d):
    return [randint(1,10) for i in range(d)]

#Main Program
d = int(input("\nHow many dice are you rolling? > "))
results = roll(d)
print(results)
```

However, I'm having trouble making the program count the number of successes in the roll. I was hoping for the output to look something like

```
How many dice are you rolling? > 2
[5, 9]
1 success
```

Any advice?

Comment: `successes = count(results, key=lambda die: die >= 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
d = int(input("\nHow many dice are you rolling? > "))
results = roll(d)
print(results)
x = sum(i >= 6 for i in results)
print([f'{x} success', 'failure'][not x])
```

Also the second last line could become:

```
x = sum(1 for i in results if i >= 6)
```

Comment: I would suggest `sum(1 for i in results if i >= 6)`; that makes the intent much clearer than relying on the detail that `True` gets converted to 1 for addition

Comment: @JiříBaum Ok, edited my answer

Comment: I've tried what you guys have recommended, but now it prints results and "failure" regardless of how many results of 6 or more there were. deleting the "failure" string from the last line of code throws me an error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Gloompunk Oh, edited my answer, sorry about that!